# How to disable email notifications for @mentions in comments field for a particular project in Jira

Tags: comments, jira, mention

I want to disable jira notifications for users mentioned as @users (or @mentions) in comments field for a particular project. Let me know if it is feasible.

Regards,

Sharieff.

Answer (score 0):

Jira has not that functionality by default, the customization is needed for this requirement. There are two solutions:

1) user `Script Runner` plugin and create you own post function for notification

2) create your own add-on for this functionality (notification should work as the first way - as postfunction)